# Is there any way I can add a chrome extension via javascript code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

So what I want to create is a Bookmark Javascript that when you run it, it will add an extension to your browser, Is there any way to do that? Let me know please. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Chrome extension can be only installed when the user clicks on the blue **Add to Chrome** button on the Chrome Web Store. That is for security reasons to protect Chrome users.
 To learn more see this official Chromium blog post:
https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/improving-extension-transparency-for.html

Before there was an inline installation for your own website. But that is deprecated
Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/inline_faq/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Ill try another solution, If anyone or you think I was gonna do this for exploits or hacking, I only wanted to do this so I can add a proxy extension on my school chromebook.